# 3D point cloud visualization is different

Tags: python, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I'm trying to do some post processing on a point cloud,
When I try to plot the point cloud using Axis3D I get different look of the point cloud, it's stretched along the axis.
When I try another point cloud viewar, I get totaly different mesh.

Here is my code
and picture

[image]

```
def main():

    #process first point cloud
    f3data = np.loadtxt(r'c:\ahmed\Waltersdorf_F3.csv', delimiter=',',
                        dtype=[('id', np.str_, 20), ('x1', np.float32), ('x2', np.float32), ('x3', np.float32),
                               ])


    ptcloud_1 = np.vstack((f3data['x1'], f3data['x2'], f3data['x3'])).transpose()



    pc_1 = pcl.PointCloud.PointXYZ(ptcloud_1)
    X = np.vstack((pc_1.x, pc_1.y, pc_1.z)).transpose()

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as m3d

    ax = m3d.Axes3D(plt.figure())
    ax.scatter3D(*X.T)
    plt.show()

    # pc_1 = pclpy.radius_outlier_removal(pc_1, search_radius=1.0, min_neighbors=4)
    #plotScatterRot3(f3rot)
    pc_type = utils.get_point_cloud_type(pc_1)
    seg = getattr(pcl.segmentation.SACSegmentation, pc_type)()
    seg.setOptimizeCoefficients(True)
    model = getattr(pcl.sample_consensus, "SACMODEL_" + 'PLANE'.upper())
    seg.setModelType(model)
    seg.setMethodType(pcl.sample_consensus.SAC_RANSAC)
    seg.setDistanceThreshold(1)
    seg.setInputCloud(pc_1)
    coefficients = pcl.ModelCoefficients()
    inliers = pcl.PointIndices()
    arr = np.ndarray(shape=(3,1), dtype= np.float32)
    arr[0] = 0
    arr[1] = 0
    arr[2] = 1
    seg.setAxis(arr)
    seg.segment(inliers, coefficients)

    inla = pc_1.xyz[inliers.indices]

    cloud_filtered = pcl.PointCloud.PointXYZ(inla)
    X = np.vstack((cloud_filtered.x, cloud_filtered.y, cloud_filtered.z)).transpose()


    pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=3)
    pca.fit(X)
    X = pca.transform(X)
    final_cloud = pcl.PointCloud.PointXYZ(X)

    pcl.io.savePCDFile("original_first.txt", final_cloud)

    import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as m3d
    ax = m3d.Axes3D(plt.figure())
    ax.scatter3D(*X.T)
    plt.show()

    pptk.viewer(X)
```

Here is the dataset

http://www.mediafire.com/file/f8tz1zbpxvyvko7/Waltersdorf_F3.csv/file

Comment: Try making a very small cloud (by hand, maybe) and use it for debugging. If the problem is only for a specific cloud, you have to include it to the question so people can try reproducing the problem. Don't expect people just staring at your code and suddenly see the solution.

Comment: are both with same axis scaling? Since the matplotlib one shows much higher dimensions on the y-axis than the x-axis and the 3D plots seems to use equal axis scaling (I guess so looking at the squares)

Comment: @qd-codie no it's not with with same scaling.. how do I fix that. I included the test data in the question

Comment: @wizzup I included the dataset

Comment: There is `ax.axis('equal')`, see here: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axis_equal_demo.html. In 3D though, you are required to set it manually with `ax.set_xlim(min,max)` etc.